# check for string and create a csv with java while reading an existing csv file

Tags: java, string, csv

i have a java code in which i m reading for a String in csv file while reading the csv file.
I create a new csv file from the existing file with 2-3 columns where i can expect my string variable which i m looking for.

Following is my csv file

```
IP,IP2,ID,PID,Abbr
"1.0.0.0","1.0.0.255","16777216","16777471","AU"
"1.0.1.0","1.0.3.255","16777472","CN","16778239"
"1.0.4.0","1.0.7.255","16778240","16779263","AU"
"1.0.8.0","1.0.15.255","16779264","16781311","CN"
"1.0.16.0","1.0.31.255","16781312","16785407","JP"
"1.0.32.0","1.0.63.255","16785408","16793599","CN"
"1.0.64.0","1.0.127.255","16793600","AU","16809983"
"1.0.128.0","1.0.255.255","16842751","AU","16809984"
```

Java code for reading

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter;


public class CSVFileReader {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    CSVFileReader obj = new CSVFileReader();
    obj.run();

  }

  public void run() {

//String csvFile = "whois.csv";
String csvFile="whois.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    String sFileName="whois2.csv";

    try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFileName); // NOT creating a new FileWriter each time you are writing a line
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // use comma as separator
            String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                if(line.contains("AU"))
                {

                    //writer.append(country[4]);
                    writer.write(country[4]);
                    writer.write(",");
                    writer.write(country[3]);
                    writer.write(",");





            System.out.println("Country [code= " + country[2] 
                                 + " , name=" + country[5] + "]");
                }
                else
                {
                    writer.write("");
                    writer.write(",");
                    writer.write("");
                    writer.write(",");
                    writer.write("");
                    writer.append('\n');


            System.out.println("");
                }


        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        if (br != null) {

            try {
                br.close();
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }

    System.out.println("Done");
  }

}
```

According the above java code i m reaidng above whois.csv file for String AU,where i m finding the string i m printing those columns and creating a new csv file.What i want is when i m creating a new file on comparing the String AU with my csv content,I want to list all AU content column values only in one column in new file althogh in original file the AU string values are in different columns.
Like AU string is present in 1st and last two rows and this csv file might get longer in future.But i m not sure about column no for this string.so i m inserting the suspected rows in new csv file.But in new csv file,i want only one column with all the AU string column values whether they are in third,fourth or anyother column,AU will present only in one column in each row of csv file...
Please guide on this...

Answer (score 0):

Put this code where you want it to start writing out the concatenated field values and it will write all field values for the current row that contain AU all in one column.

```
for (String field : country)
    if(line.contains("AU"))
        writer.write(field);
```

Comment: i want only that column value to be printed in one column,not the entire row sir..

Comment: You can add this wherever you want. You can leave your current write statements putting out field 4 and field 3 as the first two columns, then add a write for another comma, then add the code above, which will put it all in column 3.